# STRING_SPLIT by comma to different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, ssms

I am using SSMS and have a small problem regarding the `STRING_SPLIT` function. Lets say I have the following records and I want to split the gender by comma.

Now, the only way I found was how to split the gender by comma and get all the values in the column gender.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to split the gender column but put the values in the other columns, meaning Bob in Name, Smith in Surname and Male in Gender.

```
Name    Surname    Gender
-------------------------------------
                   Bob,Smith,Male
                   Jane,Walson,Female
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of the XML possibilities, but it can get expensive.   Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d336bc217bfaba08614e5adc9a7ef4a6 for a lighter alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output converting your string to XML and then taking advantage of XML type methods such as `VALUE` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)) to extract the information you need:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (OriginalString VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tmp
VALUES 
     ('Bob,Smith,Male')
    ,('Jane,Walson,Female')
;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT  
         CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(OriginalString, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    FROM @tmp
    )
SELECT
     Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [Name]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(50)') as [Surname]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(50)') as [Gender]
FROM Splitted;
```

Results:

[image]